# AWS Step Functions - Read Message from SQS Queue and Save to DynamoDb - Can't Save Messsage Attributes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sqs, aws-step-functions

I am trying to implement the step function to read from SQS and save the message to DynamoDb. I followed the tutorial on AWS and it works.

When I add Message Attributes to the message these aren't stored in the Db.

My question is how do I get step functions to find and save the message attributes?

Link to tutorial - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sample-map-state.html

Thanks,

Sean

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out and if anyone else has the same problem.

Go to Lambda functions and edit the auto generated function and add the following to the
Node.js:

```
MessageAttributeNames: ["All"],
```

Thanks to anyone who took a look at the question